# javascript: when declaring a prototype method: error is invalid left hand side for assignment

Tags: javascript-objects

I am new to object oriented javascript. Trying to make an object constructor.
Here is my code

```
function Collection() {
    this.ports = build_ports_collection();
    this.all_things = build_things_collection();
    this.added_things = function() {
        this.added_things.total_added = 0;

        var temp = this.all_things;
        temp.splice($(sth).val(), 1);
        this.added_things.all = temp;
    };
};
Collection.ports.prototype.reload = function() {
    Collection.ports = build_ports_collection();
};
Collection.all_things.prototype.reload = function() {
    Collection.all_things = build_things_collection();
};
Collection.added_things.all.prototype.reload() = function() {
    var temp = Collection.all_things;
    temp.splice($(sth).val(), 1);
    Collection.added_things.all = temp;
};
Collection.added_things.prototype.add_things = function() {
    this.added_things.total_added++;
    add_things();
};
Collection.added_things.prototype.remove_things = function() {
    this.added_things.total_added--;
    remove_things();
};
```

I am getting error in the line Collection.added_things.all.prototype.reload()=....

netbeans reports: invalid left hand side for assignment.

here my intention was to bind a method reload() to Collection.added_things.all so that it will be shared among all instances of Collection

What point i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but this came to mind.

```
Collection.added_things.all.prototype.reload() = function() {
    var temp = Collection.all_things;
    temp.splice($(sth).val(), 1);
    Collection.added_things.all = temp;
};
```

There, you are assigning stuff to the prototype of `Collection.added_things.all`, while

```
this.added_things = function() {
    this.added_things.total_added = 0;

    var temp = this.all_things;
    temp.splice($(sth).val(), 1);
    this.added_things.all = temp;
};
```

is the first to declare the `.all` on `Collection.added_things` - basically, you are trying to assign a value to a property/variable/pointer that does not exist until `added_things` is first called.